# How to use URLEncoder.encode android

Tags: java, android, urlencode

How do you use URLEncoder.encode correctly?

When I encode my string to pass my parameters to a url the `=` and `?` in my url is getting converted and breaking my php script.

This is my string that is getting encoded.

```
String spinnerURL = "getName.php?name=flowers";
```

Here is my script to encode the string and do a http request:

```
query = URLEncoder.encode(spinnerURL, "utf-8");
                Log.d(TAG, query.toString());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
                try {

                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("http://www.website.com/tattoo/" + query);
                                  }
```

When I check my logCat for TAG I see the url looks like

```
getName.php%3Fname%3Dflowers
```

I left out the catch and a few other lines of code that do not effect the url ecode and http call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's by design. You're supposed to encode the `getName.php`, `name`, and `flowers` separately.

Comment: Well that makes sense. So would I break apart the url and then enode and piece it back together?

Comment: better name it as **URLEncoder.encodeParam()** or even **URLParamEncoder.encode()**

Comment: @Denoteone: No. You URL-encode stuff when you have a bunch of user-entered strings that you don't want any special interpretation for. For example, if a user-entered string could contain `&` and you're not filtering for that, then URL-encoding that string would allow the `&` to be sent correctly, rather than starting the next parameter. So, if you're talking about "breaking apart the URL", that sounds very different from the usual use case for URL-encoding. So what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Sam: Sure, but `URLEncoder` is the name used in the JDK. There is no chance they will rename it, due to compatibility requirements.

Comment: @Chris I was encoding a string that is set in my script (not user entered) So I guess I dont have to encode it at all. I went ahead and just past the strings "as is" and everything is working as normal. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Chris Jester-Young: sure i knew it, and that is why it was in the comment. To avoid -1's. ;)